# hide a field using custom php in rules

Tags: entities, rules

Drupal 6 only:  I have a button field on a petition node for users to sign that petition. I have custom php in a rule to check if they've signed it before. If they have, I need to hide the button.

So I need php in an action to hide the button field.

(Using conditional fields according to the issue queue doesn't work with the button field)

Anyone know how to do this?  Help would be very much appreciated!